# Implement Dark Mode Toggle Button Functionality on Existing Website with React JS and Sass.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, node-sass

I Have My Portfolio Website. I want To add DarkMode Theme On my website. This website made with Reactjs, Sass and JSX Components. I want to implement that feature.Help Me to Impliement Functionality. Its Showing Compile Error Like Module Error. How to Fix this?

[App.JS to call Jsx components file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXTm3.jpg)

[ToggleButton.Jsx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4sDh.jpg)

[Added That ToggleButton in Navbar.Jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nGfx.jpg)

[ToggleButton.Sass file to design button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rrzzs.jpg)

Comment: I mean, if I just google "react sass dark mode" I see a bunch of articles outlining how to do exactly what you seem to want. What **specifically** are you struggling with? SO is for help debugging _specific_ issues, after you've tried solving yourself. This question is too vague

Comment: @Jayce444 I Searched and watchMany articles and videos.. none of them works for my website they are use different approaches i want just component (button - JSX) Design in Sass and Toggling Functionality in Js or JSX and Implementation in my App.js

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @jayce444 Now i Corrected My Question Please Watch and Clarify me.